# InnoDB inserts are pretty slow (under 1000/sec). How to increase it?

Tags: mysql, performance, bulkinsert

I have the following InnoDB table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable1` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    `text1` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `text2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `id1` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `id2` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `id3` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `id4` TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `id5` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `id6` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `num1` DECIMAL(9,4) NOT NULL,
    `num2` DECIMAL(7,3) NOT NULL,
    `num3` DECIMAL(7,3) NOT NULL,
    `num4` DECIMAL(7,3) NOT NULL,
    `text3` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I am fetching some data from a 3rd party website and store it into this table. The expected insert size is about 20 millions of rows. I'm using PHP to do the inserts. First I'm storing the data in an array and then looping through it to insert the records. I'm doing batch inserts of 200/insert. The problem is though that the inserting is pretty slow, something near to 600/second.

I'm using WAMP locally to do this so I don't see the reason why can't it insert at a faster rate. Most of the text values that you can see up there are below 50 characters.

I have an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6920HQ CPU @ 2.9GHz processor and 16GB RAM, and using SSD.

Here is my `my.ini` from WAMP:

```
; Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
;
; This is for a large system with memory of 1G-2G where the system runs mainly
; MySQL.
;
; MySQL programs look for option files in a set of
; locations which depend on the deployment platform.
; You can copy this option file to one of those
; locations. For information about these locations, see:
; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/option-files.html
;
; In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
; If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
; with the "--help" option.

; The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
;password = your_password
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

; Here follows entries for some specific programs

; The MySQL server
[wampmysqld64]
;skip-grant-tables
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size = 64M
max_allowed_packet = 1000M

;Added to reduce memory used (minimum is 400)
table_definition_cache = 600

sort_buffer_size = 20M
net_buffer_length = 80K
read_buffer_size = 20M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 20M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 256M
;Path to mysql install directory
basedir="c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14"
log-error="c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log"
;Verbosity Value  1 Errors only, 2  Errors and warnings , 3 Errors, warnings, and notes
log_error_verbosity=2
;Path to data directory
datadir="c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14/data"

;Path to the language
;See Documentation:
; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-message-language.html
lc-messages-dir="c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14/share"
lc-messages=en_US

; The default storage engine that will be used when create new tables
default-storage-engine=INNODB
; New for MySQL 5.6 default_tmp_storage_engine if skip-innodb enable
default_tmp_storage_engine=INNODB

;To avoid warning messages
secure_file_priv="c:/wamp/tmp"
skip-ssl

explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=true

; The default SQL mode in MySQL 5.7 includes these modes:
; ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.
; no line sql-mode="" gives default SQL mode
; To clear the SQL mode explicitly, set it to an empty string using sql-mode=""
;sql-mode=""
;sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"


; Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
; if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
; All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
; Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
; (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
;
;skip-networking

; Disable Federated by default
skip-federated

; Replication Master Server (default)
; binary logging is required for replication
;log-bin=mysql-bin

; binary logging format - mixed recommended
;binlog_format=mixed

; required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
; defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
; but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id = 1

; Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)

; New for MySQL 5.6 if no slave
skip-slave-start

;
; To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
; two methods :
;
; 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
;    the syntax is:
;
;    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
;    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
;
;    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
;    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
;
;    Example:
;
;    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
;    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
;
; OR
;
; 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
;    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
;    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
;    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
;    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
;    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
;    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
;    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
;    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
;
; required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
; (and different from the master)
; defaults to 2 if master-host is set
; but will not function as a slave if omitted
;server-id       = 2
;
; The replication master for this slave - required
;master-host     =   <hostname>
;
; The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
; to the master - required
;master-user     =   <username>
;
; The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
; the master - required
;master-password =   <password>
;
; The port the master is listening on.
; optional - defaults to 3306
;master-port     =  <port>
;
; binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
;log-bin=mysql-bin

; Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
;tmpdir   = /tmp/
;log-update   = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

; The InnoDB tablespace encryption feature relies on the keyring_file
; plugin for encryption key management, and the keyring_file plugin
; must be loaded prior to storage engine initialization to facilitate
; InnoDB recovery for encrypted tables. If you do not want to load the
; keyring_file plugin at server startup, specify an empty string.
early-plugin-load=""

; Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
;innodb_data_home_dir = C:/mysql/data/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
;innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:/mysql/data/
;innodb_log_arch_dir = C:/mysql/data/
; You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
; of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
; Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 60
innodb_flush_method=normal

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
; Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
;safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer_size = 2M
write_buffer_size = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size_size = 20M
read_buffer_size = 2M
write_buffer_size = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
port = 3306
performance_schema=off

innodb_buffer_pool_size=12G
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_file_per_table=ON
innodb_stats_on_metadata = OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 16
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
bulk_insert_buffer_size=1024M
```

What could be the reason behind that it's so slow and how can I possibly increase it?

**EDIT 1:**
For request I'm now providing the PHP code for inserting the data into the table.

I'm using Laravel 5.5 framework to do this.

```
$data = DataWarehouse::getData('2015-01-01', '2018-01-01');

DB::connection('mysql2')->table('myTable1')->insert($data);
```

Comment: First I'm sotring the data in an array and then looping through it to insert the records why?

Comment: @P.Salmon I meant storing. I need to store it somewhere before inserting it.  Cannot bulk insert 20M rows at once.

Comment: can you also provide the `PHP` code that is responsible for bulk inserting data to your database?

Comment: @PeterDarmis Yep, just added it.

Comment: Try removing the primary key from the table and only add the primary key once the table is populated with the 20 million rows.

Comment: You could look into [`load data infile`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) as opposed to a PHP script.

Comment: Even better I would write the data to a file and bulk load the data into the table in one go. If a 20 million row file is too big, break it down into whatever size suits. It will be much faster than individual inserts. Best to only add the primary key once the table is populated, if that is feasible for your situation.

Comment: @Steve Unfortunately removing the primary key is not an option here because there could be many duplicated results. However, writing the data out into a file sounds like an interesting option I'm going to check it out now. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: `DataWarehouse::getData('2015-01-01', '2018-01-01')` - this might be the bottleneck.

Comment: @Radical_Activity If you can't remove the primary key then I would load all the data, including the duplicates, into a temp table. Then identify the unique rows and insert those rows into your 'myTable1' table. That is, let the DBMS identify the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set 
innodb_doublewrite to 0 and
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit to 2

Increse batch size to 1000 if slower go to 300, later 400 etc.

Later iostat is your friend.
My record is 800k/s

Answer (score 0):

Batch insert in one of two ways:

- `LOAD DATA` -- but it may take extra effort to build the .csv file to use for this.
- `INSERT ... VALUES (1,2,3), (2,3,4), ...;` -- do 1000 rows per statement, but not more than, say, a megabyte string.

In either case, do it with `autocommit=ON`.  At that point, the setting of `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` will have little impact.